# Can the dimension of a space or quantity be complex?

Tags: vector-spaces, dimensional-analysis

I was wondering if the notion of a quantity having complex dimension makes sense mathematically?  It's maybe just a bad question; I can't attach any physical meaning or intuition to, for example, a vector space of dimension 2 + i, or a quantity with length-dimension -i, but I was wondering if this concept has any mathematical meaning or use.

I did some Google searching, but all I could see were links about complex vector spaces and the like, and I'm not even sure where I should begin looking to find something like this in a textbook or paper...  I did come across one post on this site

[Is there a complex analogue of the covering dimension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302877/is-there-a-complex-analogue-of-the-covering-dimension)

which mentions complex dimensions in passing, but it has no answer and I hardly understand the question.  I will continue digging into the tags once I finish posting.

Answer (score 1):

Slogan: the "dimensions" of a geometric object $X$ are the poles of its [zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zeta_functions) $\zeta_X(s)$ (whatever that is). This idea works pretty well for [algebraic curves and surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_zeta_function).

In the past couple of decades, it's been [shown to work](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~fractals/6/slides/Lapidus.pdf) for bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^N$, including fractals. In this setting, having a "complex dimension" means that, when the radius of the balls covering the set scale by $\lambda$ , the volume of the balls scales by about $\lambda^af(\ln \lambda)$, where $a$ is related to the real part of the dimension and $f$ is periodic with a period related to the imagniary part of the dimension.

Comment: I would like to know more on this. Is there an example of complex-dimensional fractal?